# Prevent user for viewing custom post type based on capability

Tags: php, wordpress, capability

I have a custom post type on WordPress, from an external plugin, and i want to conditionally deny showing content from this post type, based on user capability.
Pseudocode is better to explain than 1000 words:

```
if (!current_user_can('my_custom_capability') && $post->post_type == 'my_custom_post_type')
then
deny showing post content;
```

which filter I have to use?

I have been searching for hours, but I've found only:
[capability for custom post types](http://www.wpmayor.com/articles/roles-capabilities-wordpress/)
and [this](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types), that seems to be the closest one, but I still can't figure out how to use them. I just need to do this check on an already existing custom post type